# How to add a column to record the repetitive data in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe like this:

```
   user_id order_id
0        a        1
1        a        2
2        a        3
3        b        4
4        c        5
```

Now I want to add a column to show whether the user of each order has multiple orders:

```
   user_id order_id repetitive
0        a        1          1
1        a        2          1
2        a        3          1
3        b        4          0
4        c        5          0
```

Since a has three orders, the tag is 1. I know the method `value_counts` can calculate the result but it only shows the result after `groupby`. I want to combine it with the origin dataframe. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `groupby` and `transform` to get your counts while maintaining the same structure.

```
df['repetitive'] = df.groupby('user_id').transform('count').gt(1).astype(int)
```

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please explain the method 'transform'? Why it can return the same rows as the original dataframe rather than the result of groupby?

Comment: [`transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.transform.html) is similar to `apply` where you can apply a function to your input. However, it maintains the input's length. In this case, it allows you to add the result back to your original dataframe.